# Uploading Item Image using Square Connect API

Tags: python, square-connect

I've reviewed the examples posted in the Square Connect API documentation and the examples on GitHub, however, I can't seem to adapt these examples to the guidance on uploading images: http://docs.connect.squareup.com/#post-image

Part of the challenge is working with the Content-Type: multipart/form-data which only the image upload requires so the documentation is non-existent (with the connect-api docs).

My ultimate question is, can Square please post an example of how to upload images?  Most relevant would be an example that shows how to update multiple items with images versus just one item.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for pointing out this gap in the documentation. The function below uses the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) Python library to upload an image for an item (this library makes multipart/form-data requests significantly simpler). Note that you'll need to [install Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install) first if you haven't.

```
import requests

def upload_item_image(item_id, image_path, access_token):

  endpoint_path = 'https://connect.squareup.com/v1/' + your location + '/items/' + item_id + '/image'

  # Don't include a Content-Type header, because the Requests library adds its own
  upload_request_headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
                            'Accept': 'application/json'}

  # Be sure to set the correct MIME type for the image
  files = [('image_data', (image_path, open(image_path, 'rb'), "image/jpeg"))] 
  response = requests.post(endpoint_path, files=files, headers=upload_request_headers)

  # Print the response body
  print response.text
```

- `item_id` is the ID of the item you're uploading an image for.
- `image_path` is the relative path to the image you're uploading.
- `access_token` is the access token for the merchant you're acting on behalf of.

It isn't possible to upload images for multiple items in a single request to this endpoint. Instead, send a separate request for each item.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for your answer.  Unfortunately, I can't get this to work.  When I execute the code, it just runs without anything happening.  I should add that I did get a syntax error related to parentheses on the last line of code which I resolved by changing it to: print (response.text()).

Is there anything you see in the code that needs modification to get it to work?  Thanks in advance for your help!