# Upload product image with square connect API

Tags: asp.net, square-connect

I'm having hard time to upload product image to square using their connect API. They provide some example code in github, but it doesn't have any about image uploading. My guess is the problem is about Content-Type: multipart/form-data. I've also tried custom http request using fiddler. Can anyone show me the path to do this? I'm implementing this in asp.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out this gap in the sample code. Until we have an opportunity to add a more complete image uploading sample to our Github repo, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28078322/3233717) demonstrates using the Requests Python library to upload an item image to the Connect API.

Comment: Is there better sample code now?